# CSS :nth-child() in div display of data

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am displaying a recordset using div and want to change the background color on alternating rows. I have done this successfully in the past using an HTML table, but I can't figure it out using div.
The data displays properly, but there is no color other than the page's background color.
I assume it is something very simple that I am doing wrong, but I can't see it.

Here is the relevant code section and the CSS styles I tried (in a related css file). I tried both odd and even. Neither worked. And the ".indexrow{background-color: #94C8F2;}" doesn't work either.

```
<div class="indexrow">
    <?php
    $wa_startindex = 0;
    while(!$rsTitle->atEnd()) {
        $wa_startindex = $rsTitle->Index;
    ?>
    <div class="column left">
        <?php echo($rsTitle->getColumnVal("Title")); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="column middle">
        Issue: <a href="<?php echo($rsTitle->getColumnVal("PubFileName")); ?>" target="_blank" class="BlackHeadline3"><?php echo($rsTitle->getColumnVal("IssueID")); ?></a>
    </div>
    <div class="column right">
        Page: <span class="BlackHeadline3"><?php echo($rsTitle->getColumnVal("Page")); ?></span>
    </div>
        <?php
        $rsTitle->moveNext();
    }
    $rsTitle->moveFirst(); //return RS to first record
    unset($wa_startindex);
    unset($wa_repeatcount);
    ?>
</div> 

.indexrow{
    background-color: #94C8F2;
    width: 100%;
}
.indexrow:nth-child(even){
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.indexrow a:hover{
    background-color: #FFFF00;
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]; in particular the part about providing a [mcve]. Your question is about applying CSS to HTML. **Do** include HTML. **Don't** include PHP. **Do** include *enough* CSS to reproduce the problem. (I'd speculate that some code you haven't shown us is causing the divs to have a height of zero). **Do** use the Stacksnippets feature to provide a live demo.

Answer (score -1):

I think your mistake is putting the nth-child() on the parent? nth-child needs to go on the children you are listing out because nth-child(odd) is saying "every instance of this element that is an odd child. I think you have fallen for the common misconception that nth-child(odd) means: "any odd child of this element"

Comment: So where should I put that line of code?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).